# Moving the WordPress dashboard avatar over the admin menu

Tags: admin-menu, avatar

Is there any documentation on moving the avatar image to the top of the menu area in the WordPress dashboard?

Comment: You mean how to create a menu item that has the users name as the label and their avatar as the icon? Keep in mind the admin menu and the toolbar use very different APIs, you would be recreating, not moving/copying. It might not sound like an important thing, but it's crucial to what you're trying to do and how you research it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a custom menu item using a plugin called [Admin Menu Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/)

And you could hide the avatar using CSS, to do this you could use a plugin to insert CSS in the admin dashboard or just create your own admin.css file and insert it putting this in your functions.php file:

```
function registerCustomAdminCss(){
$src = "path/admin.css";
$handle = "customAdminCss";
wp_register_script($handle, $src);
wp_enqueue_style($handle, $src, array(), false, false);
    }
    add_action('admin_head', 'registerCustomAdminCss');
```

Where path/admin.css is the path to your admin.css file